# How to wrap Listviewitems in Listview javafx?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I am using Listview to show the list of data and I can change the orientation only two ways (Horizontal & Vertical) but I just need my data in the wrapping way like windows does in file explorer (means when we re-size the windows the icons of files folders are wrapped and they go to second line) need help or any work around.

Attaching image [image: Image showing wrapping]

Comment: Can you show an illustrated image of wrapped list item?

Comment: I see, have you looked into FlowPane and TilePane? As a name suggests ListView shows its items listed vertically or horizontally.

Comment: FlowPane and TilePane does not work with binding they does not support custom object collection type like:-

Comment: Watch [Simple Movie Catalog - JavaFX in action](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LK3B7cpZlGM), although it was made with JavaFX 1.3, it can be made also with 2.0 by using FlowPane (or TilePane) imo. Also see [FlowPane and TilePane example](http://dammsebastian.blogspot.com/2012/03/javafx-20-layout-panes-flowpane-and.html). You can bind the children nodes of these panes, whereas the panes just manages the layouts of them.